# Is Requirement engineering is obsolete in Scrum Way of working?

Tags: testing, scrum

The questions may seem strange!

In the project I am working now, Scrum methodology was adapted from the last three months. We used to follow a V- Model as it was standard in embedded industry.

Our project ran into some trouble and this decision were made. What currently is being done is that the customer (Product Owner) is giving top level requirement directly to development team, the requirements team is just a part of it.

The development team works on it and show the final outcome to Product Owner and if changes are needed it is made. Once the Product Owner is ok with the result, then the changes made are reported to requirements and they document it and pass it to test team.

What my problem with such an approach is that in this process we are technically making requirements team and test team obsolete. They come too late into the process.

Is this the way Scrum works? In this process everything is driven by development team and others basically are more or less spectator.

Some where I saw that we could still have the V-Model within the scrum methodology?

Edit:

I understand the tiny V-model releases every sprint. But my question is do they all work in parallel? For example: in the traditional V-model, which is a modified waterfall, there always was a flow - the requirement team will release the requirement to Development and test and they work parallel in designing and then once development is completed the test team starts testing. How that flow is handled in scrum way of working?

You have mentioned that "The sprint is not complete until the requirements and test parts are done for each story. " In our project at least the requirement part is being done (test team is completely kept out and the testing is more or less done by the development team on the product). But the requirement job is more or less a documentation job.,

The entire scrum is being driven by the development teams perspective. We are seeing scenarios where Development team decide the way certain function work (because the initial concept is too difficult to implement for them or may be more complex).

There is no creation of boundary at any level! Is this the way Scrum suppose to work?

The test team in the project is more or less demoralized currently. They know very clearly any issue they find at system test level is not gonna be taken care much. The usual excuse from development team is that they don't usually see the issue at machine.

Comment: You've got so many questions, it makes this impossible to answer. I'm marking as too broad. Please consider breaking this up into smaller/single questions. Or perhaps just focus on the headline question, which I've answered.

Comment: Consider posting on [programmers.se] after you've followed Dave's advice and pared this down to a reasonably-scoped question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a separate requirement engineering team is obsolete in the Scrum way of working. You should all be working together.

Scrum suggests that you should be working in multidisciplinary teams and working in small increments. You can think of this as doing tiny v-model releases each sprint. The sprint is not complete until the requirements and test parts are done for each story. You should consider them part of your definition of done.

I'd suggest a good point for you is to actually read the [Scrum Guide](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v1/scrum-guide-us.pdf). It has the following to say about the make up of development teams:

> - Development Teams are cross-functional, with all of the skills as a team necessary to create a product Increment;
> - Scrum recognizes no titles for Development Team members other than Developer, regardless of the work being performed by the person; there
>     are no exceptions to this rule;
> - Scrum recognizes no sub-teams in the Development Team, regardless of particular domains that need to be addressed like testing or business
>     analysis; there are no exceptions to this rule; and,
> - Individual Development Team members may have specialized skills and areas of focus, but accountability belongs to the Development Team as
>     a whole.

As an aside, I have some experience working in an embedded system with Agile methods and we had great success using automated testing to replace manual testers. Our testers, pretty much because responsible just for running the test suite on various hardware, physically running the tests. We even had the tests fully built into the production process; every new piece of hardware went through (a subset of) our test suite straight off the assembly line!